# Join all the images to their relative page

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, content-management-system

I have two tables in a mysql database: pages and images (for now, I prefer that the “images” are text). I need that every page show all their relative images. For example: page one shows 3 images, page two 4 images, page three has no images and so on. In order to do that I created (following basic cms tutorial

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbsAdx58ch0&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF0O8kS5D_3-nTzsFiPMOfM)

two tables into a database:

`Pages:`

```
id,label,title,body,slug,created,updated
```

`Images:`

```
id,page_id,content (for now, I prefer that the “image” is text)
```

Unfortunately my queries can only show one image, and not all the images relative to the page, and I don’t know why. Here u are the query into the page.php:

```
require 'app/start.php';

if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = false;
} else {
    $slug = $_GET['page'];

    $page = $db->prepare("  
        SELECT pages.id, pages.label, pages.title, pages.body, pages.slug, pages.created, pages.updated, images.id, images.page_id, images.content AS image_content

        FROM pages

        LEFT JOIN images
        ON pages.id = images.page_id

        WHERE slug = :slug

    ");

    $page->execute(['slug' => $slug]); 

    $page = $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($page);

    if ($page) {
        $page['created'] = new DateTime($page['created']);

        if ($page['updated']) {
            $page['updated'] = new DateTime($page['updated']);
        }
    }
}

require VIEW_ROOT . '/page/show.php';
```

This query produces the following source, relative, for example to the page one:

```
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["label"]=>
  string(20) "This is the first page"
  ["title"]=>
  string(22) "This is the first page"
  ["body"]=>
  string(8) "Some text"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(10) "first-page"
  ["created"]=>
  string(19) "2015-10-05 10:55:54"
  ["updated"]=>
  string(19) "2015-10-05 10:55:54"
  ["page_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["image_content"]=>
  string(8) "groundhog"
}
```

How u can see, image_content shows only one result, but the page_id of images tables recorded more than one images linked to the id of the page. Where am I wrong?

Then i tried this solution:

```
<?php

require 'app/start.php';

if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = false;
} else {
    $slug = $_GET['page'];

    $page = $db->prepare("  
        SELECT pages.id, pages.label, pages.title, pages.body, pages.slug, pages.created, pages.updated, images.id, images.page_id, images.content AS image_content

        FROM pages

        LEFT JOIN images
        ON pages.id = images.page_id

        WHERE slug = :slug

    ");

    $page->execute(['slug' => $slug]); 

    $page = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($page as $key) {
        $select[] = array('created'=>$key['created'], 'updated'=>$key['updated'], 'image_content'=>$key['image_content'], 'title'=>$key['title'], 'body'=>$key['body']);
}

    var_dump($key['image_content']);

    if ($page) {
        $key['created'] = new DateTime($key['created']);

        if ($key['updated']) {
            $key['updated'] = new DateTime($key['updated']);
        }
    }
}

require VIEW_ROOT . '/page/show.php';
```

Now I am a little bit more near to my goal, but with this code I get the same name of the image repeated for the number of times that the page id is repeated into page_id column.
So page 1 has 4 images and the final results is: "horse horse horse horse".
page 2 has 3 images so: "cat cat cat"

here u are show.php:

```
<?php require VIEW_ROOT .'/templates/header.php'; ?>

    <?php if (!$page): ?>
        <p>No page found, sorry.</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h2><?php echo e($key['title']); ?></h2>

        <p><?php echo e($key['body']); ?></p>

        <p class="faded">
            Created on <?php echo e(($key['created']->format('jS M Y'))); ?>
            <?php if ($key['updated']): ?>
                last updated <?php echo e(($key['updated']->format('jS M Y h:i a'))); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <br/>
            Images:
            <?php foreach($select as $result): ?>
                <?php echo e($key['image_content']); ?><br/>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </p>

<?php endif;?>

<?php require VIEW_ROOT .'/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Show the PHP code that runs this query. Edit your question, **dont add it to a comment**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only [fetching one row of your result](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php). If you want to acces the whole result of your SQL-Query you either have to fetch the result with [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php/) or process each row individually as you loop through the result.

1. **Use fetchAll:**

   `$page_array = $page->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
2. **Use a loop:**

   `while($page_row = $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   { //do stuff }`

**Edit:**

If you change your loop in show.php, it should work.

```
<?php foreach($page as $result): ?>
                <?php echo e($result['image_content']); ?><br/>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**fetchAll:**

fetchAll returns an multidimensional associative array. For each row in your query-result, another row is added to the array. If your query returns 3 rows you can access them throug $page[0]['variables'] to $page[2][variables]. See [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-php-5/0596005601/ch04s05.html).

**key-Element**

I would consider the usage of the last key-array after your foreach-loop very bad practice. See the first warning on the [manual-page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: I tried as u suggested,but i still not match my goal. What is wrong? I edited the main topic

Comment: @user3323340 
**1.** What are you trying to accomplish with your $selected? All the information is already in the associative array $page.

**2.** The var_dump has to be inside the loop.

Comment: Iskar, within $selected[] I store all the information into specific variables. If i use fetchAll I can't then use $page['values'] directly without getting Undefined index message error

Comment: I add the show.php, so u can see how I use the selected[] array. Insterting var_dump into the foreach don't solvemy problem.

Comment: Thanks Iskar, it works. U are right I have to learn a lotmore and study more deeply. I am learning so much those yeras but I could do more, u right.
The "see here" link report a no-existent page.

Comment: Edited the link, but there seems to be a Problem with safaribooks. I will check again in the morning. So do i... Keep up the hard work and have fun doing it ;)

Comment: So i used e($page[0]['value']) to fill the various variables. It works perfectly and without do the foreach loop. IS this a good solution?